# Compare moment objects jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to check if my timestamp and the current time is the same day but it does not work. It is always false even when the dates match.

```
{% if moment().format("MMMM DD, YYYY") == moment(room_params.timestamp).format("MMMM DD, YYYY") %}
    <span class="time-info">{{ moment().format("HH:mm") }}</span>
{% endif %}

# Outputs below
moment().format("MMMM DD, YYYY") # September 16, 2020
moment(room_params.timestamp).format("MMMM DD, YYYY") # September 16, 2020
```

I have also tried the `| string()` filter but that too does not work.
What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because `moment().format("HH:mm")` returns an HTML span element like this:

```
<span class="flask-moment" data-timestamp="2015-03-26T10:58:51" data-refresh="False"
 style="display: none">2015-03-26T10:58:51</span>
```

I solved this issue by creating a js function and while the page is loading I check the timestamps and the returned result is applied to my `span` element.

```
<span class="time-info">
    <script>
          document.write(checkDate('{{ room_params.timestamp }}'));
    </script>
</span>
```

Then the js:

```
function checkDate(date) {

    var currentDate = moment.utc();

    var refDate = moment.utc(date);

    var currentDateinDateFormat = currentDate.local().format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
    var refDateinDateFormat = refDate.local().format("MMMM DD, YYYY");

    var currentDateinYearFormat = currentDate.local().format("YYYY");
    var refDateinYearformat = refDate.local().format("YYYY");

    if (currentDateinDateFormat == refDateinDateFormat) return refDate.local().format("HH:mm");
    if (currentDateinYearFormat == refDateinYearformat) return refDate.local().format("MMM DD");

    return refDate.local().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
}
```